# PHP code doesn't print any value

Tags: php, html, forms

[image]

Here i entered name nd email id but when i click on submit button my entered information is blank like below image.

[image]

In PHP clicking on the submit button doesn't print the information. I used `$GET` and `$POST`, both are not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<body>

<form action="php_forms.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you install a server web, like Wamp or easyphp ?

Comment: Are both your files php files?

Comment: @Rishi she is already using `post`

Comment: `<form action="php_forms.php" method="get">` change to `<form action="php_forms.php" method="POST">`

Comment: @JoelEnanodJr doesn't matter if she writes `POST` or `post`

Comment: Is there anythign printed? Anything in the log files? Are you sure the second snippet of code is in `php_forms.php` and is in the correct path so the page with the form can call it?

Comment: @Rishi , i don't know , why people post different codes while asking and then changes again

Comment: @Epodax it was method="get" when I posted my previous comment.

Comment: @bfahmi yeah i already have wamp server

Comment: can you please use $_REQUEST replace with $_POST

Comment: @AmmyJohn, and the both files are in your directory web like www ?

Comment: @epodax first file is html nd other one is in PHP

Comment: Check your send data
<?php print_r( $_POST ); ?>

Comment: Do you get any results or redirects when you press submit?

Comment: @ dhaval bhavsar not working

Comment: @AmmyJohn : Is your php file named `php_forms.php` and `html form` file are in same directory ?

Comment: @ronald rozema when i click on submit button its only print php value not user name nd email address

Comment: what is file name can you please post here

Comment: Right now what is the Output you are getting? Add that in the question

Comment: When i run this code on my pc it works just fine, so i dont think the error is in the code itself.. What are your file names?

Comment: file name are forms.html & php_forms.php

Comment: @RonaldRozema i add screen shot of my output code. hope its understandable now what i am trying to say

Comment: @Arun i add screeshot of my output...

Comment: Have you started your wamp server? it looks like it is opening the php file as a regular file not as a webpage. The php wont show if it opened as a regular file. Try accessing it in the url ike so: "http://localhost/forms.html"

Comment: @AmmyJohn, give your directory structure to the file inside wamp

Comment: @AmmyJohn, The url should be `localhost/Day50/php_forms.php` for php file and `localhost/Day50/your_form.html` for html file

Comment: @Arun thnk u so much :-) it works now

Comment: @AmmyJohn, Glad to hear that. Happy to help

Comment: @Arun sure i will....

Answer (score 1):

It should be work.Change your action (`php_forms.php`) file code.I have tried in my server.Hope it will be helped.

```
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Read More dealing with html forms in **[PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).**

Comment: 100% it will be worked if your action file name and location is correct.See my output http://prntscr.com/bt6pcg

Answer (score 0):

Your form uses get method and php_forms.php uses post method. Try

```
<form action="php_forms.php" method="post">
```